# Fill Multidimensional Array with two variables in loop

Tags: perl, for-loop, multidimensional-array, while-loop

I am new to PERL and I try to get the following result in a loop:

```perl
# ResultFistStep.
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'Hello1'
          ],
          [
            'Hello2'
          ],
          [
            'Hello3'
          ],
        ];
```

But if i use a reference for the InnerArray `\@InnerArray`:

```perl
# Example1
my @OuterArray;
my @InnerArray;

foreach(1,2,3)
{
    @InnerArray[0] = "Hello" . $_;
    push(@OuterArray, \@InnerArray);
}
print Dumper \@OuterArray;
```

... i get this result:

```perl
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'Hello3'
          ],
          $VAR1->[0],
          $VAR1->[0]
        ];
```

If i try it without the reference:

```perl
# Example2
my @OuterArray;
my @InnerArray;

foreach(1,2,3)
{
    @InnerArray[0] = "Hello" . $_;
    push(@OuterArray, @InnerArray);
}
print Dumper \@OuterArray;
```

.. i get this result:

```perl
$VAR1 = [
          'Hello1',
          'Hello2',
          'Hello3'
        ];
```

But what i want is the result shown at the beginning (**ResultFistStep**) and at some point in the end the following result (**ResultFinally**):

```perl
# ResultFinally
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'Hello1', 
            [
               [], 
               []
            ]
          ],
          [
            'Hello2', 
            [
               [], 
               []
            ]
          ],
          [
            'Hello3', 
            [
               [], 
               []
            ]
          ],
        ];
```

So the questions are:

1. How do i get this result for the **ResultFirstStep** done?
2. Can i solve the problem from **ResultFinally** with Perl?

Can please someone help me? I dont see the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use anonymous arrays:

```
my @outer;
push @outer, [ "Hello$_", [ [], [] ] ] for 1 .. 3;
```

or even

```
my @outer = map [ "Hello$_", [ [], [] ] ], 1 .. 3;
```

If you want to use the inner array, declare it inside the loop, otherwise you're reusing the same array again and again:

```
my @outer;
for (1 .. 3) {
    my @inner = ( "Hello$_", [ [], [] ] );
    push @outer, \@inner;
}
```